# unlocking restrictions for Java Domino agent

Tags: java, lotus-domino

I need to unlock restrictions for a Java Domino agent. I read the java policy file on the Domino server need to be altered.

In development I could set:

```
grant { permission java.security.AllPermission; };
```

But if I want to restrict this allowance for a single Agent/Application how do I do this?

For Xpages I could do:

```
grant codeBase "xspnsf://server:0/yourdatabase.nsf/-" { 
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

But will this also allow the all permissions allowance for an Java Domino agent in that NSF?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you can't. I've spent many hours in exact this question. But Java agents and script libs don't have a code base you can refer to. It might be possible with code signing - i didn't try that. Or you can put your code into a jar file in the file system (with all the caveats).
On the other hand: Permissions are a rail to keep developers from unintentionally doing harm, not a security feature (any more). Any Java code in any agent can easily get AllPermission. I don't see much benefit in restricting permissions in production.